# Encoding base64 in Java and decoding in C#

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, encoding, base64

Im having problems whith base64 between java and c#, im sending encoded string to a asp.net handler from an java urlconnection, i compare both strings, the one generated in java from byte array and the one received in asp.net first decoding and both are identical but after decode the byte array in c# arent equal from byte array in java.
Im using new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(javabytearray); in java and System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedstring); in dotnet.


from java: "[0] [-24] [56] [1] [-56] [41] [-29] ........."

to dotnet: "[0] [232] [56] [1] [200] [41] [227] ........."


Similar: [Encoding base64 in Java and decoding in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410203/encoding-base64-in-java-and-decoding-in-c)

 i cant ask it in question above because it is an Q&A site and every time an new question must be created, cant ask an question inside another question.

thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like bytes in -128..0 range are converted to 256+b in c#. Loss of sign somewhere.

Comment: Mate - thanks for this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`byte` is unsigned in C# and signed in Java. The bit pattern of the Java `byte` value `-24` is equal to the bit pattern of the c# `byte` value `232`. So your code should be correct. If you want to verify this, convert e.g. the Java `byte` values to `int` and add `256` to the negative values.

Comment: To expand on Aasmund's answer all you have to do is convert the result of FromBase64String to an unsigned byte[].  You could also just write your own method that gives you an unsigned byte result.

Comment: @Ramhound: Good point, except that I guess it must be done the other way (since the C# bytes are already unsigned) - the `byte[]` can be converted to `sbyte[]`.

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot for so fast answer, i have a third-party biometric software that have {byte[] buffer = t.serialize()} ,  {t.unserialize(buffer)} and {t.unserialize(stream)} in both sides, cant pass signed byte array in dotnet side.